# Unexpected token Error while upgrading react in nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to upgrade to React 18 in nextjs app. I followed [instructions](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/overview#using-react-18-with-nextjs) in official docs.

`npm install next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest`

But when I try to run `npm run build` I get the error:

```
/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:329
                    ...pageKeys.app ?? [],
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
```

I've tried to google this error, but there was no luck

Comment: What's your node.js version?

Comment: Hi! node version is `12.22.3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current [next.js (13.0.0) requires](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v13.0.0/docs/getting-started.md#system-requirements) node 14.6.0 or newer:

> ##### System Requirements
>
> - [Node.js 14.6.0](https://nodejs.org/) or later
> - MacOS, Windows (including WSL), and Linux are supported

The error you see is because some of the next.js code is using a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). This language construct was introduced in [node 14.0.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Following acdcjunior's answer, if anyone wants terminal commands to update node version, they can do this :

```
nvm install v (Whatever latest stable version is running currently)
```

If any issues with above, try this:

```
npm install n stable -g
```

If you get permissions issue, do this:

```
sudo su
npm install n stable -g
```

And Just to be sure, you can do this:

```
npm use v(Whatever you downloaded)
```